# find and delete duplicate data in registry using powershell

Tags: powershell, duplicates, registry

did anyone create a script in powershell to search registry for duplicate entries?
I got following situation:
"**home**" is containing sub-keys.
"**sub-keys***" contain values: "**path**" and "**datetime**" filled with data

**Sub-key1**

*path*: C:\temp\Test

*Datetime*: 02/12/2021 18:23:12

**Sub-key2**

*path*: C\temp\Test

*Datetime*: 02/13/2021 12:54:13

Goal is to search in "home" for all sub-keys having same path and delete older entry (checking value in "datetime") --> "Sub-key1" in example above

Comment: Deleting stuff from the registry can lead you into **serious** trouble. What makes you think any of `Sub-key1` or `Sub-key2` can be removed?

Comment: These are custom keys which will be used by another program but its able to work with 1 value only

Answer (score 1):

You can search through registry keys in PowerShell just as easily as you can sort through files and with many of the same cmdlets.

#### Requisite Warnings...

However, you should heed @Theo's warning.  **There be dragons**

The registry is by its nature, hierarchical.  You cannot have duplicate keys in a hierarchy, so be careful and be sure you know what you're doing.

#### How to effectively shoot one's own foot

Now, here's how to do it.  I made this registry tree:

[image]

I can look at these values using the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet, the same cmdlet we use for looking at files.

```
get-childitem HKCU:\SOFTWARE\StackOverflow
 Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\StackOverflow


Name                           Property                                                                                               
----                           --------                                                                                               
Entry1                         UserName : FoxDeploy                                                                                   
                               UserID   : 1                                                                                           
Entry2                         UserName : FoxDeploy                                                                                   
                               UserID   : 1                                                                                           
Entry3                         UserName : FoxDeploy                                                                                   
                               UserID   : 1
```

Your next task is to write some code to determine if you've seen a value before, and if so, do the right thing.  You could do this by building an ArrayList and then checking to see if it contains a value.

If it Does...then do something.  If it doesn't contain the value, we haven't seen it before, so we should store it for the future.

Writing the rest is up to you.

```
$SeenValues = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

gci HKCU:\SOFTWARE\StackOverflow | % {
   $regValues = get-itemproperty $_.PSPath
   "Path: $($_.Name), value = $($regValues.UserName)   "
   If ($SeenValues.Contains($regValues.UserName)){
        "   We've seen this UserName $($regValues.UserName) before, we should do something..."
        #Do Something
   }
   else{
        "   We have not seen this UserName $($regValues.UserName) before, we should store it"
        $SeenValues.Add($regValues.UserName) | out-null 
       }
}
```

Output

```
Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\StackOverflow\Entry1, value = FoxDeploy   
   We have not seen this UserName FoxDeploy before, we should store it
Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\StackOverflow\Entry2, value = FoxDeploy   
   We've seen this UserName FoxDeploy before, we should do something...
Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\StackOverflow\Entry3, value = FoxDeploy   
   We've seen this UserName FoxDeploy before, we should do something...
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. This is a great hint, thanks a lot for that. I think I can continue working with that :)